# Powershell - Invoke-Webrequest (Error 503 when run via script)

Tags: powershell

I have a script that parses a website for download links to TV shows I follow, copies the links of any new episodes, at which point J-Downloader takes over.

The script was working fine up until a few days ago when, apparently this website implemented some sort of browser authentication. `Invoke-WebRequest` is returning the following:

> Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

The website is rapidmoviez.com. Either this base website or a specific show website (e.g. www.rapidmoviez.com/the-walking-dead) returns blank `$links` when run through the script.

```
$links = invoke-webrequest -Uri "www.rapidmoviez.com/the-walking-dead"
$links = $links.Links
```

The website loads fine within a browser but comes up to a "Checking your browser before accessing Rapidmoviez" screen if I clear my cache.

I tried specifying the useragent header as suggested elsewhere but that yielded the same results.

```
$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,     like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
$test = Invoke-WebRequest 'www.rapidmoviez.com' -Headers @{"User-Agent"=$useragent} -Method Get
```

Really appreciate any assistance!!

Comment: It has CloudFlare sitting in front of it. That tends to cause problems for scripts.

Comment: no way around it? I don't care if the script has to open IE, download the page, and then parse the local file. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Comment: I don't have any suggestions, but that doesn't mean there isn't one. Just letting you know that's most likely the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not with your code but with your connection.
I just run these same command and got the results just fine:

```
PS> $links.count
3269
```

Comment: That is very interesting. I wonder if they flagged my IP or something since I was accessing via a script.. Seems like "small fish" but maybe.. Strangely enough, I was able to work around it using the function on this http://poshcode.org/2498 which utilizes the Net.WebClient object. Not as clean as invoke-webrequest but it does work. THANKS!

Comment: Just FYI. This stopped working again last night (with the new method). Wasn't connecting to the site like before. Finally switched to msxml2.xmlhttp.

Comment: Further clarification in case this is happening to someone else.... I used the internetexplorer.application object before but my "body" was always empty. msxml2 works (similar code found here http://scriptolog.blogspot.com/2007/08/query-http-status-codes-and-headers.html). I do need to create a new object, and run $ie.navigate to my page, run the msxml script block, and $ie.quit. The original issue does not appear to be specific to that particular connection. I used a phone hotspot to check if they were limiting me based on MAC or IP, but got the same results (error 503)